# why doesn't php Ajax pass value to php file?

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I have two files: the first is named `semester_1.php` and the second is named `pagination.php`. I am trying to pass the value of subjects from `semester_1.php` to `pagination.php` and then to query and output it. I used javascript and Ajax to get value of href and then passed it to another file, which is `pagination.php`. the problem is that I have no display and no error, here is the codes, can anyone please help? It is worth mentioning that both files are in the same directory in case of accessing.

semester_1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    height: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;

}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 520px;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagenation.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>


<script>
$(function(){
    $('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr('href');
        var p = n.slice(5, 6);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'pagenation.php',
            data: {value : p},
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something with response 'data'
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#sub=1">Introduction to Programming</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub=2">Fundamental of Programming</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub=3">Afghan History</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub=4">Mathematics</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub=5">Islamic Study</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub=6">English</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="sub=1">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>
<div id="sub=2">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>
<div id="sub=3">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>
<div id="sub=4">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>
<div id="sub=5">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>
<div id="sub=6">
<br><br>
<?php include('pagenation.php');?>
</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pagination.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Papermashup.com | PHP Pagination</title>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pagenation.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>



<?php
$dbhost                         = "localhost";
$dbuser                         = "root";
$dbpass                         = "";
$dbname                         = "LMS";



$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to database");

mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $tableName="presentation";      
    $targetpage = "Lecture.php";    
    $limit = 10; 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    $stages = 3;
    $page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
    if($page){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else{
        $start = 0; 
        }   

    // Get page data
        $data = $_POST['value'];
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE Sub_ID='$data' LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
    $prev = $page - 1;  
    $next = $page + 1;                          
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    


    $paginate = '';
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   




        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1){
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }



        // Pages    
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
        {
            // Beginning only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // Middle hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // End only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
            }
        }

                // Next
        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }

        $paginate.= "</div>";       


}
 //echo $total_pages.' Results';
 // pagination
 echo $paginate;
?>


    <?php
$data = $_POST['value'];
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['Pre_Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['pdesc']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['pdatein']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='{$row['Path']}' title='download file' target='_blank' >Download</a><br />"?></td>


    </tr>
    <?php }
 ?>








</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your jQuery you use POST method and in your PHP code you use $_GET['value'];

try $data = $_POST['value'];

Comment: tell me if this help you or not

Comment: Dear jetawe, I also changed that one as well, but still problem is remain

Comment: can you print me the request using echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST); die;   and show what request have

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get your question

Answer (score 0):

You have issue of type of data is passing with POST method and you try to get with GET method so best solution is you can use $_REQUEST so, you will get both POST or GET.

```
// Get page data
$data = $_REQUEST['value'];
```

OR

remove this line from your $.ajax call

```
// type: 'post',
```

Let me know if you have still issue.

Regards

Comment: Dear Mr. Chaudhary, I did your first soultion, but still same like before, but regarding the second option, you mean that I should delete all code of ajax or just the name of $.ajax?

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me what input you have pass in 
var p = n.slice(5, 6);

Means is that object or Single value ?

Comment: I passed the href attribute which is #sub=1,so because I need just value of subject ID, I sliced it and just get the number and put it in where class of my query
<li><a href="#sub=1">Introduction to Programming</a></li>

Comment: also make this line change >>  $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

Comment: i change that portion as well, still problem is